# Memory allocator for ROS2 messages?

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RCL has allocators to have custom memory management, that are taken from rcutils. Tests while doing my Ada binding show that this works nicely. I'm now trying to understand where a message allocator is configured. For example, in the rosidl-generated `bool__functions.h` there is:

`bool std_msgs__msg__Bool__Array__init(std_msgs__msg__Bool__Array * array, size_t size);`

and in general any array message is dynamically allocated (I think). I'm trying to ascertain what I should add to my binding to also provide allocators for messages. Thanks for any pointers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295736/memory-allocator-for-ros2-messages?/) by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering to myself, it is under evaluation: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues/306

---

Originally posted by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) with karma: 43 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-23**:
Yeah definitely an issue with eventual consistency, the rosidl stuff is just older and hasn't been updated just yet.